# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: radix 482 greater than Character.MAX_RADIX

Tags: java

Lately I have been having an issue with my game, this:

```
@Override
public Tile getPlace(List args)
{
    return new CraftingTableTile(Integer.valueOf((String)args.get(0), 
    Integer.valueOf((String)args.get(1)).intValue()).intValue(), this.healthrep);
}
```

as well as:

```
s.map[selectedx][selectedy] = s.mp.inven.i[s.mp.invsel].getPlace(args);
```

gives an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: radix 482 greater than Character.MAX_RADIX
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at net.spideynn.miner2d.CraftingTableItem.getPlace(CraftingTableItem.java:21)
    at net.spideynn.miner2d.MainGame.mousePressed(MainGame.java:851)
    at org.newdawn.slick.Input.poll(Input.java:1217)
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:641)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
    at net.spideynn.miner2d.MainGame.main(MainGame.java:2074)
```

Any Ideas?

(Sorry if the answer is easy, I couldn't find a solution.)

Comment: How many args are you trying to pass into your `CraftingTableTile` constructor: 2 or 3?

Comment: So obviously `args.get(1)` is `"482"` which is greater than `Character.MAX_RADIX`. Java can't parse base 482. What do you need help with exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your are attempting to pass 3 values into your `CraftingTableTile` constructor, but because of a mistake in your parentheses, you are passing only 2 arguments:

```
//             v This parenthesis...
Integer.valueOf((String)args.get(0),
// is balanced by this parenthesis                v
   Integer.valueOf((String)args.get(1)).intValue()).intValue()
```

and

```
this.healthrep
```

Because of the parentheses mixup, two arguments are being passed to [`Integer.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), with the second being interpreted as a radix.  The exception comes from `482` being greater than the maximum possible radix.

You probably meant to pass these 3 arguments:

```
Integer.valueOf((String)args.get(0))
```

and

```
Integer.valueOf((String)args.get(1)).intValue()
```

and

```
this.healthrep
```

Like this:

```
return new CraftingTableTile(
    Integer.valueOf((String)args.get(0)),
    Integer.valueOf((String)args.get(1)).intValue(),
    this.healthrep);
```

Incidentally, your constructor probably is taking `int`s, in which case you can use `parseInt`.  The only difference between `parseInt` and `valueOf` is that `parseInt` returns an `int` and `valueOf` returns an `Integer`.

```
return new CraftingTableTile(
    Integer.parseInt((String)args.get(0)),
    Integer.parseInt((String)args.get(1)),
    this.healthrep);
```